# Как работает проекция с камер в three.js?

Tags: 3d, three.js

Не могу понять, как работает проекция векторов с использованием камер на three.js

Вроде, на обычную проекция векторов не похоже, ссылки из официальной документации на википедию ясности не внесли

На картинке пример проекции:

```
new THREE.Vector3( 5, 7, 0 ).project( camera );
```

[image: пример проекции]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался как происходит unproject

Если смотреть из камеры, то можно рассматривать текущую видимую область, как прямоугольник с углами (-1; 1), (1; -1)

Бардовыми точкам отмечены unproject векторов {1; 1; 0} и {1; 0; 0} из этой самой камеры

project операция обратная unproject

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]